# Screen only updating when moving my mouse over it, is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: python, pygame

Here's the code:

```
# Initialize the pygame
pygame.init()


# Create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))


# Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


# Player
playerImg = pygame.image.load("player.png")
playerX = 370
playerY = 480


def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))


# Run game until x is pressed

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        playerX += 0.1
        print(playerX)

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.display.quit()
            sys.exit()

        player(playerX, playerY)
        pygame.display.update()
```

For some reason the screen only updates when i move my mouse over it or when i spam a button on my keyboard. I don't have any more details to add so i have to type this otherwise i can't post my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your indents. You only need to check event type in the event loop. The draw code is under the `while` loop.

```
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.display.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    playerX += 0.1
    print(playerX)
    
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: thanks, I feel really stupid now lol (kinda new to programming)

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to update the screen application loop rather than the event loop:

```py
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    #<--| INDENTATION

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    playerX += 0.1
    print(playerX)

    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.dispaly.flip()
```

Comment: you're right i feel really stupid now lol, well atleast i can continue :)